# How to change hop limit of IPv6 in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, ipv6

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_min_hop_limit = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.hop_limit = 65
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_min_hop_limit = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.hop_limit = 65
net.ipv6.conf.enp0s25.accept_ra_min_hop_limit = 1
net.ipv6.conf.enp0s25.hop_limit = 65
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra_min_hop_limit = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.hop_limit = 65
net.ipv6.conf.wlp7s0.accept_ra_min_hop_limit = 1
net.ipv6.conf.wlp7s0.hop_limit = 65
```

But when I ping, wireshark shows me hop limit is still 64.  What is going on?

Using Arch Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The `ping` utility creates raw packets with their own hop limit set. By default `ping` uses a hop limit of 64, but you can change it with the `-t` option.

```
ping -6 -c1 -t128 www.google.com
```

[image: Wireshark packet capture showing Hop limit: 128]

If you mean to check whether outgoing traffic has the hop limit set correctly as in your sysctl, you should create some real traffic using something like your actual workload.

Comment: `ping` with IPv4 uses same TTL as set by `sysctl`.  I confirmed this with Arch GNU/Linux and Gentoo GNU/Linux for IPv4, and confirmed this with Gentoo GNU/Linux for IPv6.  With Gentoo GNU/Linux, changing IPv6's hop limit `sysctl` works as expected, but I don't know Arsch GNU/Linux does not behave so.  Both of them (Gentoo GNU/Linux and Arch GNU/Linux) are with using `systemd`.  (I put an up vote because I liked that you reminded to manually set the TTL for `ping` for my troubleshooting, thanks a lot!)

Comment: @caveman I suppose it depends on the version of `ping` your Linux distribution is using. I used `ping` from [iputils](https://github.com/iputils/iputils) which is the version installed on Red Hat based systems. Neither Arch nor Gentoo are common around here as this site is focused on professional IT operations. In any case, if you want to be 100% sure about the hop limit, send some real traffic.

Comment: My Arch also uses `core/iputils 20190709-2`.  I suspect your RedHat is using old versions, which is typical of RedHat, Debian, etc.  Arch and Gentoo are often on the bleeding edge.

Comment: Um, it's 20190515, so I guess that's old :) Of course, being bleeding edge is one of several reasons Arch and Gentoo are not commonly used.

Comment: Gentoo GNU/Linux is commonly used.  It's just that it is used by the few elites of the interwebs who choose USE flags and regularly apply custom patches.  We're so elite we don't eve like the latest upstream packages, so we keep adding our custom patches to it, effectively we're actually living in about 2025 right now.  At least me.

Comment: @caveman Again, this site is for professional IT operations. Gentoo is very rare here.

Comment: What is the definition of "professional IT operations"?